# Getting 6 months from a specific date

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I get six months difference in a date?

Example:

I want to make a formula to give me exactly 6 months from this date 1/29/14.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-dates-HP003056112.aspx#BMadd_a_number_of_months_to_a_date

Comment: It depends. What date would you consider to be six months from 30 August?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [edate](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/edate-function-HP010342465.aspx) function

`=EDATE("1/29/2014",6)` or `=EDATE(A1,6)`

If you want six months previous, just change `6` to `-6`